# Code completion not working in Clion 2019.1 for c++2a

Tags: c++, g++, clion, c++20

I have Clion 2019.1 and gcc-9.0.1(trunk). Code completion and syntax analyser don't recognize the `concept` keyword and other c++2a features released in gcc-9.0.1.

In `CmakeLists.txt` i use `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20` and compilers flags `-fconcept -std=c++2a`
The code compiles fine.

Comment: That's more of a statement than a question, really. Please take some time to review [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, for syntax highlighting and code completion CLion don't use the compiler used for building your project. You should probably report this as a bug or a feature-request on [the JetBrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/).

Comment: Actually, there is such a feature request 3 years ago... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6584

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Clion supports coroutines key-words and it depends on the selected compiler. If i use clang intellisense recognizes ```co_await``` keyword, but if i use gcc intellisense doesn't recognize this (undefined symbol).

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `-fconcepts` command line option as described in https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

This may help.

Comment: I highly doubt that would influence the IDE's intellisense features. Not to mention that the OP already mentioned to use this feature.

Comment: It would be good SO track timeline a little bit better. Update on original question was made after my answer here.